# Dictionary Values to List from HashSet of Keys

Tags: .net, linq, dictionary, hashset

Hopefully the comments explain the question.   I have a large static (gets built with fresh data on program load) dictionary that is used a lot and I want to reference it as efficiently as possible rather than create copies of the data and eat memory.  Have a hashset the represents a subset of that dictionary that I need to represent as a sorted list of values.  New HashSet or changes to the HashSet then I build a new class that wraps the code below.  Is there a better way to go about this?  I could not figure out how to use  an external HashSet in LINQ.

```
// FTSwordIDs is a hashset and is also used elsewhere - a lot - hashset for lookup speed
// dlFTSword is Dictionary<Int32, string> and is static and sorted by value (on load) 
// dlFTSword can contain over a million entries and is used a lot of places 
// need to refence it rather than build a new list and eat memory
words = new List<string>();
foreach(Int32 id in dlFTSword.Keys)
{
    if (FTSwordIDs.Contains(id)) words.Add(dlFTSword[id]);
}
return words;
```

The time is 12 ms

```
try
{
    sqlConRO1.Open();
    sqlCMDRO1.CommandText = "SELECT [ID], [word] FROM [FTSwordDef] WITH (NOLOCK); "; // ORDER BY [word]; ";
    SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCMDRO1.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        dlFTSword.Add(rdr.GetInt32(0), rdr.GetString(1));
    }
    rdr.Close();
    Debug.WriteLine("dlFTSword.Count = " + dlFTSword.Count.ToString());

}
catch (Exception Ex) { throw new Exception("InitializeData Failed " + Ex.Message); }
finally { sqlConRO1.Close(); }

HashSet<Int32> wordIDs = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 600000 };
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

//List<string> words = dlFTSword.Where(pair => wordIDs.Contains(pair.Key))
//         .Select(pair => pair.Value)
//         .OrderBy(x => x)
//         .ToList();
//List<string> words = wordIDs.Where(key => dlFTSword.ContainsKey(key))
//          .Select(key => dlFTSword[key])
//          .OrderBy(value => value)
//          .ToList();
IEnumerable<string> words = wordIDs.Where(key => dlFTSword.ContainsKey(key))
          .Select(key => dlFTSword[key])
          .OrderBy(value => value);
DateTime dtEnd = DateTime.Now;
stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
Debug.WriteLine(ts.Milliseconds.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
var words = dlFTSword.Where(pair => FTSwordIDs.Contains(pair.Key))
                     .Select(pair => pair.Value)
                     .ToList();
```

Note that this avoids performing a lookup on each key after finding that it's present. We don't actually look *anything* up in the dictionary. It also doesn't involve creating any other sets, which `Intersect` would.

This is worth checking though:

> dlFTSword is Dictionary and is static and sorted by value (on load)

If it's a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` then it *isn't* sorted. There's no such concept as a "sorted" `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. You could use a `SortedDictionary<,>` or `SortedList<,>`, but those are both different to a `Dictionary<,>`.

EDIT: If the hash set is really small, it makes more sense to iterate over *that* than over every pair in the dictionary:

```
var words = FTSwordIDs.Where(key => dlFTSword.ContainsKey(key))
                      .Select(key => dlFTSword[key])
                      .OrderBy(value => value)
                      .ToList();
```

It's slightly ugly to have to do the lookup, but it'll be significantly faster.

Comment: I was afraid of that but a SortedDictionary is not going to fix my problem as i need the output sorted on Value not Key.  Nice trick on pair.  I will test it out.   Then what would be the syntax to sort the value?

Comment: @Blam: You can't make a Dictionary<,>` order itself by anything. It's not clear at what point you need it to be sorted - please clarify.

Comment: I only need it sorted when I produce the List string of words.  When I create the dictionary I can produce the list sorted easily as it comes from a database not sure that does me any good.  The HashSet is only about 200 in length.  Lots of operations where I need to know if an Int is in the HashSet but I produce the sorted list of words to the UI relatively seldom.

Comment: @Blam: In that case, just add a call to `OrderBy(x => x)` after the `Select` in the code I've given.

Comment: @Blam: Yes, it filters before ordering. But it sounds like you should be able to do it faster... will edit. (Done.) I'd expect this to really fly - much faster than 9ms!

Comment: Thanks!  Tested against a dictionary of 660,000 and a HashSet of 8 and got the sorted list of words in 120 milliseconds on a P4.  It must be smart enough to select before is sorts.  Works great. I can definitely generate that List on the fly and save memory.

Comment: @Blam: 120ms is *definitely* slower than it needs to be - try the second version.

Comment: Second version is 46 milliseconds.  The dictionary is going to average 100,000 larger than the HashSet.  There are some admin functions that I need to produce the whole list sorted and I use dlFTSword.Values.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();  Up to 1 million that works OK but over 100 million I get into minute response time.  I am thinking about a second reverse lookup SortedDictionary string, Int32. You have any thoughts.

Comment: @Blam: It shouldn't take 46ms to check for 8 values in a HashSet, to be honest... that's very surprising. Any chance you can produce a complete program to show it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8982/discussion-between-blam-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @Blam: Sorry, chat doesn't really work well for my usage pattern.

Comment: OK then let's unchat.  I tried IEnumerable<string> words = wordIDs.Where(key => dlFTSword.ContainsKey(key)).Select(key => dlFTSword[key]).OrderBy(value => value); and it came down to 15 ms.  I just need to bind to a ListBox so I think IEnumerable will do.  Heck, I was happy with 120 ms but if it can get faster then I will test anything you want.

Comment: @Blam: Are you using `DateTime.Now` to measure the time, out of interest? Multiples of 15ms seem suspicious to me :) If so, try using `Stopwatch` instead... then I suspect you'll see it be slightly faster. Of course, it's only the user experience that really matters, so if you're happy...

Comment: Sorry my earlier code post did not stick - it is posted now.  That was ms (not second).  I cannot measure milliseconds with a stop watch.

Comment: @Blam: I wasn't talking about a physical stopwatch - I was talking about `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` which is designed for measuring how long things take, and has higher resolution than `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: Now that is funny.  System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch is way more accurate than my pocket watch.   12 ms

Comment: For a sorted total list I added a reverse SortedDictionay<string,Int32>.  What I found interesting is SortedDictionary does not sort the same as SQL but that is OK.

Comment: @Blam: That's not `SortedDictionary`, that's just string comparisons in general. There are various different options in .NET - see `StringComparer` for details.

Comment: Thanks again. Changed my program to use the same StringComparer for all comparisons.  Used IgnoreCase so hopefully equality will be the same as SQL.

Comment: Found a way to have a what is basically an ordered dictionary.  A KeyedCollection preserves order.

Answer (score 1):

```
var words = dlFTSword.Keys.Where(FTSwordIDs.Contains).Select(x => dlFTSword[x])
```